# FindInstance confused by CoprimeQ

Tags: functions, programming, boolean-computation, findinstance

For some reason when I type

```
FindInstance[a + b == c && CoprimeQ[a, b, c] == True, {a, b, c}, Integers]
```

Mathematica just immediately returns my input as its output, even though the very simple solution {1,2,3} should suffice. Why doesn't it even attempt to solve for this, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

As with most *Q functions, [`CoprimeQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoprimeQ) will evaluate to [`True`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/True) or [`False`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/False) immediately:

```
CoprimeQ[a,b,c]
```

> False

You could instead use [`GCD`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GCD):

```
FindInstance[
    a + b == c && And @@ Thread[GCD @@@ Subsets[{a, b, c}, {2}] == 1],
    {a, b, c},
    Integers
]
```

> {{a -> 1, b -> 0, c -> 1}}

although this approach won't work to find your example.